# Correct way to update Centos 5 as much as possible?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a CentOS 5.4 system that cannot be taken down for a major version upgrade in the short-term. I would like to bring it up to 5.11 (the last minor version of 5 released). Because 5 is in EOL archival, the package mirror lists are broken and in order to install updates  I will have to point it to the archives at http://vault.centos.org/. Should I point it at 5.11 and yum update, point it to the current minor version and update, or something else?

Comment: Is it CentOS 5.0 ? Please add the exact version to your question : `cat /etc/redhat-release` . .... ( 5.11 repo file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SOWQMpErI-JAfp7FYRq73tytWJQu24_X/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: I have edited the question to contain the version number (5.4).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to find a good answer.  However, there are many good practices that could be applicable while performing upgrades.  One of the statements "cannot be taken down" tells me "we have zero tolerance of this system going down".  Every system goes down eventually, and no system has perfect uptime, and data will always get lost.  Protect your organization, protect yourself with lots of planning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update to the lastest CentOS 5.11 you need to remove all previous repos in your system.

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/*repo
```

then create new file `/etc/yum.repos.d/centos-updates.repo`

```
[repo]
name=CentOS Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
#proxy = http://uncomment.if.you.have.proxy.com:3128
```

and new file `/etc/yum.repos.d/centos-os.repo`

```
[repo]
name=CentOS OS
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
#proxy = http://uncomment.if.you.have.proxy.com:3128
```

This assumes you are using a 64-bit installation.  If you are on 32-bit, change x86_64 to i386 in the two files above.

Then run

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Now you will have 5.11.

Direct Upgrades from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6 are not supported, but there are some variants.

Safest Migration:

1. Take and test a full backup of the old system.
2. Bring up a second system with CentOS-6 either on new hardware, or on an alternate set of disks/partitions.
3. Port over applications, data, and settings for users and the system from CentOS-5 to CentOS-6 looking for file and application syntax and operational differences.
4. Look for /etc/*.rpm* configuration files backups left over from updates and compare old to current versions, adapting as required.
5. Take down old system and move to new system.

Other variants are written [here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide/MigratingFiveToSix)